# Pandas DataFrame Interpolate TypeError:: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation

I am trying to interpolate for NaN values in a dataframe where all the columns are dtype float64.
While the default 'linear' method works:

```
doseframe3 = doseframe2.interpolate(method = 'linear', axis = 1, limit_direction = 'both')
```

Almost any other method (e.g. 'cubic' or 'quadratic') throws up a TypeError:

> TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Just to clarify :

- All columns are dtype float64
- I've tried converting the index and columns to float64 without any benefit

Need help.
The data before interpolation is here:
[Data before interpolation](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cmjo7brq3kf16c9/tomo_beforeinterpolation.csv?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

I realized that the conversion of the column names to float64 had not worked. Once I did that successfully the interpolation worked well.

The key point seems to be the use of the index (when interpolating within a column) or the column name (when interpolating across the row). This cannot be an object or str.